# How to create a cinematic animation of geospatial data

Tags: python, netcdf, animation

I got a couple of NetCDF4 (imageCollections) datasets with a temporal component. I would like to create a compelling movie to display on social media. In the past I successfully used [Panoply](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/download/) but the result is not very cinematic. I would like to generate something like [this](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4096)

Is there a programmatic way to generate cinematic (define camera position and angle, add lights, shading) movies using for example python?

Comment: "Cinematic" is a bit vague here. You want a rendered earth globe with your data superimposed, with a moving camera and the data changing in time? Could you do it with Google Earth or Cesium?

Comment: I added some details about what I consider cinematic. Cesium and Google earth go a long way but I am not sure if they allow lights and shading (e.g. similar to cinema4D)

Comment: I found this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCyiHJ-q9NI

Comment: would panda3D be an option?

Comment: If a cinema 4d script existed that could access the netCDF library via it's python interface (http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) that would be INCREDIBLE! Does anyone know whether that exists somewhere or would be possible to create??

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148455)